# Visual Studio 2022 html tag characters are doubling <<ddiivv

Tags: html, tags, visual-studio-2022

Just installed VS 2022. However, when I am adding html tags the characters are doubling like this: <<ddiivv. I have searched all over but have not found where anyone else has had this issue. In the short term I decided to go with just typing "div" and then tabbed which creates the div tag like I need. However, this will not work when I need to add a class. Adding a class results in doubling up the characters like so: ccllaa... and so on. I have repairing VS using the VS Installer and restarted. That did not work so I am giving it another try to see if it will fix the issue. Has anyone else encountered this issue and if so, how was it resolved? Thx.

Comment: Yes, I reboot ever day. I also tried just using the laptop keyboard. I only have this issue with tags, not any other text. Also, tried repairing again and restarted but have the same result

Comment: Someone has pointed out the following link where another developer has encountered this issue (link below). This resolved my issue. Hope it helps someone else if they run into this. 

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/double-characters-when-typing-html-tags-in-cshtml/1637052